# Is it possible to create non-printable pdf with using jasper or itext in java?

Tags: java, pdf, jasper-reports, itext

I want to create non-printable pdf with using jasper, however users can display pdf but they can't print pdf. I don't want any pdf password restriction. I've researched jasper documentation but i couldn't found anything about it.

Is there anyway to solve my issue? I've already thank to you for your helps.

Comment: jasper doesn't allow you to do that. You can do it with some property changes to the file. You can restrict the printing of that document.

Answer (score 1):

You can use iText's [PdfStamper](http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/itext5/5.5.12/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfStamper.html) to post-process your PDF :

```
byte[] pdfContent = /* your PDF content here */;
ByteArrayOutputStream stampedPdfContent = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfContent);
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, stampedPdfContent);
stamper.setEncryption(null, null, ~(PdfWriter.ALLOW_PRINTING), PdfWriter.STANDARD_ENCRYPTION_128);
stamper.close();
pdfContent = stampedPdfContent.toByteArray(); // your PDF is now non printable
```

Comment: yea this is another way to achieve that

Comment: The OP said *"I don't want any pdf password restriction."* Strictly speaking this excludes your solution as you use password encryption (even though it is one default password and one randomly generated, unknown one).

Comment: @mkl The problem is that in the PDF format, the restriction of printing is tied with setting a "Permissions Password". See [this page on Adobe's website](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/how-to/security-permissions-protect-pdf-files.html), for instance. So, if you want to disallow printing, you have to set a password.

Comment: I'm aware of that. In my eyes the answer, therefore, should be "There is no way."